# Why don't i have the "Api Controller - Empty" as an option while creating a new controller in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried to create a new controller for a new project while following a tutorial, but his visual studio community has a lot of options inside the creation of the API Controller - Empty, and this is one of the options. When I tried to create it is only appears to me "assembly information file", "machine learning model", 2 typescript options, and 2 JSON options.

It's my first time creating an API in ASP.NET, so I have no idea why I don't have the "API Controller - Empty" option

Comment: specifically what project template did you choose?

Comment: Api Web ASP.NET core, the one that has a key in the draw, I'm using the 5.0 version

Answer (score 0):

Press right mouse button on the `Controllers` folder in your project, then follow this:

`Add -> Controller... -> API -> API Controller - Empty`

Comment: but that's the thing, when i do it the option it's an assembly file and I don't know why

Comment: Can you provide screenshot and what is the version of the IDE you are using? @AmandaScremin